# Reading objects within an arraylist

Tags: c#

Thanks in advance for any help I get here. I am trying to get the values of objects within an arraylist. I have an ArrayList of sandwiches, each sandwich is made up of a topping, a type of bread and a price. I have no issues with creating each individual sandwich, then adding that sandwich to the collection. Yes I am sure many will say "Why are you using arraylist?" I have no great reason other than I am trying to learn at least how to use it, and I have just as much skill in using a list.

```
ArrayList Sandwiches= new ArrayList();
ArrayList thisSandwich = new ArrayList();

thisSandwich.add("Ham and cheese");
thisSandwich.add("Wholemeal");
thisSandwich.add(4.50);
Sandwiches.add(thisSandwich);

thisSandwich.add("topping2");
thisSandwich.add("bread2");
thisSandwich.add(price2);
Sandwiches.add(thisSandwich);

thisSandwich.add("topping3");
thisSandwich.add("bread3");
thisSandwich.add(price3);
Sandwiches.add(thisSandwich);
```

From here, how do I display and get the values for what the topping was for sandwich 2? Or how do I display and get all of the values of sandwich 1

Comment: is that Java, not C#?

Comment: the order in the Arraylist depends on the order added making the while thing fragile.  For instance sandwhich one has 3 pieces of info, the others 2.  So you never know what is where.  Use a Sandwich class and a List<Sandwich> for the collection

Comment: The first rule of using `ArrayList` is not to use it... (Learning how to cast objects to different types does not require usage or understanding of `ArrayList`)

Comment: Won't compile, it's `Add` not add. And just don't try to learn it, it's outdated. It's not strongly typed, so you'd have to cast everything. Use a `list<T>`

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrifying design.  But if you insist on going down this path of insanity, here's one reasonably efficient way to do it.

```
ArrayList[] sandwichArray = Sandwiches.ToArray(typeof(ArrayList));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Topping for sandwich 2 is {0}", sandwichArray[1][0]));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Price for sandwich 1 is {0}", sandwichArray[0][2]));
```

Comment: I hate to accuse but my guess is this is a homework assignment.  The parameters of the exercise are so arbitrary and ridiculous.

Comment: My thought as well.  The references to sandwiches is a bit of a giveaway.  I remember many assignments revolving around the "Sandwich Shop"

Answer (score 0):

```
        ArrayList Sandwiches = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList thisSandwich = new ArrayList();

        thisSandwich.Add("Ham and cheese");
        thisSandwich.Add("Wholemeal");
        thisSandwich.Add(4.50F);   // cast these as floats so you know they will convert correctly
        Sandwiches.Add(thisSandwich);

        // remember to clear out your sandwiches from the array or they will accumulate
        thisSandwich = new ArrayList();
        thisSandwich.Add("topping2");
        thisSandwich.Add("bread2");
        thisSandwich.Add(5.45F);
        Sandwiches.Add(thisSandwich);

        thisSandwich = new ArrayList();
        thisSandwich.Add("topping3");
        thisSandwich.Add("bread3");
        thisSandwich.Add(6.71F);
        Sandwiches.Add(thisSandwich);

        // this will get you the total cost of the sandwiches
        float total = 0F;
        foreach (ArrayList al in Sandwiches)
        {
            float f = (float)al[2];
            total += f;
        }
        // this will get you the cost of sandwich #2
        ArrayList s2 = (ArrayList)Sandwiches[1];
        float costOf2 = (float)s2[2];
```

Comment: Sandwiches should be a List and thisSandwich should be an individual sandwich i.e an object of Class Sandwich. then what you are doing make sense.